# redirection fails

Tags: bash, terminal, io-redirection

I've written [a script](https://github.com/twomasz/snapserver.on) integrating PulseAudio with [Snapserver](https://github.com/badaix/snapcast). I have one bug I can't get rid of. It's in this line (line 183 in [the source](https://github.com/twomasz/snapserver.on/blob/master/snapserver.on) at the moment):

```
snapserver -s pipe:///tmp/snapfifo?name=Radio&mode=read 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

It starts Snapserver as a user daemon. The thing is that it keeps logging to the terminal despite the redirection. I don't know how this is possible and would like to stop it.

The process becomes a detached process when its terminal is closed, so I've been thinking of starting it detached already if that's possible. Something like `bash --notty`. Snapserver itself doesn't have any options for logging redirection as far as I've checked.

Is there any option like that in Bash? Sh? And why's the redirection failing anyhow?

Comment: The & in the middle should be quoted?

Comment: @JeffSchaller That's it. Now I know why [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) says _mode appears unused_. The whole line should be `snapserver -s 'pipe:///tmp/snapfifo?name=Radio&mode=read' &>/dev/null &` as the `-d` option doesn't work somehow. You can compose an answer if you want. I will otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue seems to be the `&` in the URL after "Radio" and before "mode". It ends the snapserver command and begins a new one (a variable assignment whose output is redirected), leaving the snapserver output *not* redirected.

Per your comment, the revised command is:

```
snapserver -s 'pipe:///tmp/snapfifo?name=Radio&mode=read' &>/dev/null &
```

Comment: Also note that generally the redirection `1>foo 2>foo` and `&>foo` are _not_ the same. In the first form the standard output and error messages overwrite each other, since the file position is maintained separately for each. In the second case they are appended after each other. Obviously for `/dev/null` it doesn't matter, still, it's preferable to get used to use the latter form.